# Thread-lock by ParameterInstance.lockObject, does it work?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, thread-safety, networkstream

I've googled far and wide and found no answer to this. I am programming my own little Tcp library to make it easy for myself. On the server I have a 'ConnectedClient' object that has a socket and a network stream. On the server static class I have a Send function that sends a length-prefixed stream. I want the stream to be thread safe, but for each client. Would this work for that?

```
Send(ConnectedClient client, ...(rest of parameters nor relevant))
{
lock (client.lockObject)
{
// Writing to stream thread-safely I hope...
}
}
```

I hope I made myself clear enough, if not, just ask for more details.

Comment: "... to make it easy for myself..." Wouldn't using a pre-built library be even easier?

Comment: @dlev while *true*, if we ***all*** waited to use something pre-built, there wouldn't be anything to use ;p

Comment: It is indeed true. I should have stated that this was also for the sake of learning something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are writing some kind of multiplexer. Indeed, that should work fine as long as you write an entire payload (and length-prefix) within a single `lock`, and as long as the `lockObject` is representative of the mutual-exclusive resource (i.e. must be a common `lockObject` for all clients that we don't want to collide).

Perhaps the trickier question is: are you going to read the *reply* within that method (success/return-value/critical-fail), or are you going to read the reply asynchronously, and let the next writer write to the stream while the first message is flying...

For comparison, when writing [BookSleeve](http://code.google.com/p/booksleeve/) (a redis multiplexer, full source available if you want some reference code), I chose a different strategy: one dedicated thread to do all the writing to the thread, with all the callers simply appending to a thread-safe queue; that way, even if there is a backlog of work, the callers aren't delayed.

Comment: I have a packet class that have a memorystream that I can write to when sending and those pile up in a queue upon input and the byte[] rercieved is lodaded into the stream. The length and a byte to make identifying the kind of message easier. Then I try to make sure everything is read upon input, like while(recv < dataLength) {recv += NetworkStream.Read(dataBuffer, 0, dataLength - recv); } The recieved data is then put into a Packet (my class) instance and piled up in a queue (generic list) that a method checks upon a timer tick or a while loop.